# Animation of images in css3

Tags: html, css

I want to change opacity of a background image (both the images are same), but the changing should be of `30 to 45 degree`

Also this animate `front image` to `background image` then again the `backgroung image` to `front image`

Two images are:

[image]
and
[image]

I want the animation like if the first image is shown then after some time second will be shown but its height should be grown from 0 to max height of the image. Also the animation should be of angle `30 degree`

I used the code

**HTML:**

```
    <div class="img_shake">          
        <img id="img_shake" src="img_shake.png" alt="img_shake">    
    </div>

    <div id="div_img_shake_patchwork">
        <img id="img_shake_patchwork" src="img_shake_patchwork.png" alt="img_shake_patchwork">  
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#main-container{
    position: relative;
    top:0%;
    left:0%;
    height: 480px;
    width: 320px;   
    overflow: hidden;       
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-position: center center; 
    opacity:1;
}


#img_shake {
    position: absolute;
    right: 27%;
    opacity: 0;
    top: 27%;
    z-index:2;
}
@-webkit-keyframes img_shake_anim
{
    from {right:-30%;}
    to {right:27%;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes img_shake_anim_again
{
    from {left:27%}
    to {left:0%}
}
@-webkit-keyframes img_shake_fade_in
{
   0%    {opacity:0;}
   100%  {opacity:1;} 
}


#img_shake_patchwork {
    width:100%;
}


#div_img_shake_patchwork
{
    position:absolute;
    top:27%;
    right:27%;  
    overflow : hidden;
    z-index:2;
    height:277px;
    opacity:0;
}

@-webkit-keyframes div_img_shake_patchwork_anim
{
   0%    {height:0;opacity:1;/*-webkit-transform: rotate(-30deg);*/}  
   100%  {height:277px;opacity:1;/*-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);*/} 
}
```

Comment: create a demo to show what exactly you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By changing the style it can be done:

```
#img_shake_patchwork {
    width:148px;/*Width of Image*/
    -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
    left: 22%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
}

#div_img_shake_patchwork
{
    position:absolute;
    top:26%;
    left:6%;  
    overflow : hidden;
    z-index:2;
    height:277px;/*Height of Image*/
    opacity:0;
    width:296px;/*Double width of Image*/
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-30deg);
}

@-webkit-keyframes div_img_shake_patchwork_anim
{
   0%    {height:0;opacity:1;left:-16% ;top:30%; }  
   100%  {height:277px;opacity:1;left:6%; top:26%; /*-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);*/} 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`background-image` will not do transitions. You need to use `position: absolute` and `z-index` to put one image on top of the other. You can then transition the `opacity` of the top image.

Comment: I am not using `background-image`,I used the `img` tag for this, also I have given the `swf url` in my question for reference.